# AWS CodePipeline Fails: "Exception while trying to read the task definition artifact filef rom: SourceArtifact"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

I have an AWS CodePipeline setup that is meant to pull from CodeCommit, use CodeBuild, and then do a Blue/Green deployment via CodeDeploy.

I believe it to be configured correctly (will discuss specifics below), but every time I get to the "Deploy" stage, I get the error message:

`Invalid action configuration: Exception while trying to read the task definition artifact file from: SourceArtifact`

I've looked through other SO answers, and I've checked the following:

- `SourceArtifact` is well under 3MB in size.
- The files `taskdef.json` and `appspec.yml` are both inside the `SourceArtifact` (these are the names as configured in my CodePipeline definition) which is generated in the first stage of the CodePipeline.
- The artifact is able to be decrypted via KMS key as the CodePipeline is configured to make use of one (since `SourceArtifact` comes from a different account) and the CodeBuild step is able to successfully complete (it creates a Docker image and saves to ECR).
- I can see no syntax errors of any kind in `taskdef.json` or `appspec.yml` as they're essentially copies from working versions of those files from different projects. The placeholder names remain the same.

Checking CodeTrail and checking `list-action-executions` (via CLI) don't show any additional error information.

Here's the "Deploy" stage config (as entered via a Terraform script):

```
 stage {
      name = "Deploy"

      action {
        name = "Deploy"
        category = "Deploy"
        owner = "AWS"
        provider = "CodeDeployToECS"
        version = "1"
        input_artifacts = ["SourceArtifact", var.charting_artifact_name]

        configuration = {
          ApplicationName = aws_codedeploy_app.charting_codedeploy.name
          DeploymentGroupName = aws_codedeploy_app.charting_codedeploy.name

          TaskDefinitionTemplateArtifact = "SourceArtifact"
          AppSpecTemplateArtifact = "SourceArtifact"

          TaskDefinitionTemplatePath = "taskdef.json"
          AppSpecTemplatePath = "appspec.yml"

          Image1ArtifactName = var.charting_artifact_name
          Image1ContainerName = "IMAGE1_NAME"
        }
      }
    }
```

taskdef.json (account numbers redacted):

```
{
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT_NUM>:role/fargate-iam-role",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/sentiment-logs",
          "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "sentiment-charting"
        }
      },
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "cpu": 0,
      "environment": [],
      "mountPoints": [],
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "image": "<IMAGE1_NAME>",
      "name": "sentiment-charting"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": "4096",
  "compatibilities": [
    "EC2",
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:<ACCOUNT_NUM>:task-definition/sentiment-charting-taskdef:4",
  "family": "sentiment-charting-taskdef",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
    },
    {
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
    },
    {
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
    },
    {
      "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
    }
  ],
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "cpu": "2048",
  "revision": 4,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "volumes": []
}
```

appspec.yml:

```
version: 0.0
Resources:
  - TargetService:
      Type: AWS::ECS::Service
      Properties:
        TaskDefinition: "<TASK_DEFINITION>"
        LoadBalancerInfo:
          ContainerName: "sentiment-charting"
          ContainerPort: 80
        PlatformVersion: "LATEST"
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how best to continue troubleshooting without spinning my wheels. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Can you try with `appspec.yaml`, not `appspec.yml`.

Comment: Even though it's specified exactly in the config? Also, I've used this exact same confg elsewhere and it's worked just fine. Thanks, though.

Comment: any update on this issue?

Comment: Sadly, nothing yet. I've had to move on and hope to come back to this at some point. For now, I've just placed all the resources necessary within the same account. I'd still love to get to the bottom of this, though.